# Read a binary file into stack instead of heap

Tags: c++, memory-management

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
void dump_buffer(void *buffer, off64_t buffer_size)
{
  off64_t i;
  for(i = 0;i < buffer_size; ++i)
  {
     printf("%02x \n", ((unsigned char *)buffer)[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void ReadFile(std::string fn)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(fn.c_str(), "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", fn.c_str());
        return;
    }
    struct stat64 fsStatBuf;
    stat64(fn.c_str(), &fsStatBuf);
    off64_t fileLen = fsStatBuf.st_size;
    // fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    // fileLen=ftell(file);
    // fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    unsigned char *buffer;
    buffer=(unsigned char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
                fclose(file);
        return;
    }
    fread(buffer, 1, fileLen, file);
    fclose(file);
    dump_buffer(buffer, fileLen);
    free(buffer);
}
```

`fread` reads a file into a block of memory, that is, the heap.
Is there a way to read the file into the stack?

Comment: Why do you want it on the stack? How big might the file be that you're reading?

Comment: No specific reason, just curious whether this can be done and why people generally use the heap for this kind of stuff.
:)

Comment: How big a file can the stack handle?

Comment: that depends on compiler settings (at least on windows based systems). i would not try to store objects of unknown size on stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - assuming that your stack is large enough to hold `fileLen+1` items, you can do this:

```
unsigned char buffer[fileLen+1];
```

and skip the call to `free()` at the end. This works, because C99 allows you to make arrays of variable size. In C++, however, this would not work <sup>*</sup>. Since most of your program is in C, however, you should be able to use the standard C construct by using a C99 standard-compliant compiler.

Note, however, that unlike `malloc` that would return `NULL` on failure, letting you handle the out of memory situation when the file is too large, this way of allocating memory in the automatic area (i.e. on the stack) will crash your program right away.

Also note that since the file is not a C string, you do not need `fileLen+1`; `fileLen` would be sufficient to fit the entire file.

<sup>*</sup> There are compilers that provide a C++ language extension to support variable-length arrays, but the resultant code would not be standard.

Comment: please note that this requires c99 support of your compiler.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch "please note that this requires c99 support of your compiler" I did. Most C compilers, with the notable exception of pre-2012 VS, are like that these days.

Comment: i doubt that most compilers are c99 compatible. that may fit for some of the most spread PC-Compiler. But not for all the custom manufacturer provided embedded compiler.

Comment: @unwind "Clearly?" OP had a C tag there, and there's nothing C++-sish about it, apart from misguided use of `std::string`.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Embedded compilers are often named C compilers by mistake. In reality, these are custom languages vaguely based on C syntax.

Comment: when is reading into the stack better than reading into the heap?

Comment: @qed readin itself may not make any difference (beside maybe some cache effects). its more a question of memory management and correct allocation and deallocation. also a lot of small dynamic allocations may be slow. but you only need one block and compared to disk access every allocation is super-fast.

Comment: @qed When it comes to reading a full file, the answer is "never". The time that it takes you to allocate and de-allocate the memory for your file is tiny in comparison to the time that it takes to actually read the file, even if you read it from the fastest, modern solid-state drive.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't understand the gray zone that people seem to feel exists here. If a program uses a C++ standard library class, and namespaces, then it can't be C.

Comment: The gray zone exists because C++ was initially touted as being a superset of C and now it's being presented as a completely different language. C++ is sort of trying to have it both ways.

Comment: @unwind There's no "gray zone" here, OP is definitely compiling this with a C++ compiler. However, this is where C++ ends. The rest of the code is regular C: it uses `malloc` instead of `new[]`, uses C formatting throughout, C I/O libraries, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be more portable to have:

```
unsigned char buffer[MAXFILESIZE];
```

and then check the filesize before writing, and fail if the file is too large.